# Dispatch events to child

Tags: android

I have a ListView containing items with one button each and I want to handle user events in this order:

1. TouchEvent on *ListView*.
2. TouchEvent on *ListItem*.
3. Click on Button inside *ListItem*.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand correctly, with a single user click, you want to trigger the event (but not catch it) for each one of those items?   You can't.   I'd make either the list item or the button the clickable item, handle that, and do all of the logic you need to do in that handler.